# How to fire alert after overall progress bar hits 100% on FancyUpload

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I can't seem to figure out where to place my alert to fire when the overall progress bar hits 100% in the FancyUpload plugin.

There is an event named, "complete" that fires after all the files are finished uploading but before the progress bar hits 100%.

```
onComplete: function() {
this.status.removeClass('file-uploading');
if (this.size) {
    this.overallProgress.start(100);
} else {
    this.overallProgress.set(0);
    this.currentProgress.set(0);
}
alert("all files done"); 
},
```

The above code fires my alert after the files are done uploading but the progress bar is still at 0. After hitting OK on the alert, the progress bar fills to 100%.

Any help setting this up so my alert fires after the overall progress bar hits 100% would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
onComplete: function() {
    this.status.removeClass('file-uploading');
    if (this.size) {
        this.overallProgress.start(100);
        alert("all files done"); // <--put it here.
    } else {
        this.overallProgress.set(0);
        this.currentProgress.set(0);
    }

},
```

Comment: Ok I added my alert there. Now it seems to fire randomly around 90%-95%.